# Document signed by SHA-2 can be verified using SHA-1?

Tags: cryptography

I am devloping an application which can sign the document with SHA-128 & SHA-256 both. the confusion is now is if I sign a document with SHA-256 can it be verified with SHA-128 or vise versa?

Answer (score 2):

SHA-128 does not exist. Maybe you mean SHA-1?

In any case the answer is no. If the document is signed with SHA-256 you must use SHA-256 to verify it.

More in general, when you verify a digital signature you must apply the exact same cryptographic hash algorithm that the originator used.